# cannot mount SD card on ubuntu server

Tags: mount

I've a problem. I run ubuntu server on usb. And during installation I also used SD card as a swap space.

But the problem is that it's not being mounted at all.

If I check df I only see usb key - no sign of swap space, or another partition on it.

any ideas how to get to that partition?

p.s. even under /media/ I cannot find it.
p.p.s. using mount command doesn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swapon -s
```

is the right command to control your swap. Swap is not displayed when invoking the `mount` command. `free` is another option to find out about swap.

Sample output:

```
swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda8                               partition   2056280 11080   -1

free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1025756     995180      30576          0      76648     238908
-/+ buffers/cache:     679624     346132
Swap:      2056280      11080    2045200
```

If your sd-card is always present and usable as swap, put an entry into /etc/fstab, and use swapon -a.

Comment: adding entry to fstab and using swapon -a helped.

thanks!

Comment: I removed my chatty comments, and included the summary into my answer. I invite you, to clear your comments too (too chatty). :)